# Using vm Instead of $scope - Angular $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having trouble converting some Angular code. Currently, it is using Angular's $http service to get data from another file and display it on the page. I want it to still do this but with `vm` instead of `$scope`. Here's an example of my vain attempts to do this:

HTML

```
<h1>{{vm.welcome}}</h1>
```

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function() {
   $http.get("welcome.htm")
   .then(function(response) {
      var vm = this;
      vm.welcome = response.data;
   });
});
```

Also, I originally got this code from w3schools' [Angular tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_http.asp).

Comment: Can you show where you bind your controller (`ng-controller`) in your HTML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `var vm = this;` outside of the promise and inside of the controller.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($http) {
    var vm = this;
    $http.get("welcome.htm")
        .then(function(response) {
            vm.welcome = response.data;
        });
});
```

in the html use controller as reference the controller

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl as vm"> 
   <h1>{{vm.welcome}}</h1>
</div>
```

refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605917/this-vs-scope-in-angularjs-controllers?answertab=active#tab-top) for get more detail about how `this` work in controller

Comment: This doesn't seem to work... If you go to the link I provided, does it work for you?

Comment: did u inject `$http` to your controller `app.controller('myCtrl', function($http)`